# How I should construct Response object, to serve images/attachments from DB in Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, httpresponse

Symfony2 abstracts Request and Response objects, how I should create Response object, to serve client file attachments, and images for browser display?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [IgorwFileServeBundle](https://github.com/igorw/IgorwFileServeBundle) which allows you to break the response abstraction to gain performance. If you are using nginx, you can also take advantage of its [XSendfile](http://wiki.nginx.org/XSendfile) functionaliy.

Note: Lighttpd and Apache have an alternative XSendfile implementation with some differences and are not supported yet. Pull requests welcome.

Comment: Yep, I saw yours bundle, one thing: On the http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php manual I saw lots of comments about problems and few ways to setup headers to solve them, and I not see any of these ways in yours code, you're sure that this will work with an old and new browsers?

Comment: octet-stream is the default content type, you can pass the disposition as an option. I do not have any special handling for apache (apache_setenv should not be used, as it requires the apache PHP extension). Regarding readfile(), I am not sure if it's still an issue in PHP 5.3. If you find any evidence that it is, I'd be glad to fix it. And if you have other improvements, feel free to send me a pull request.

Answer (score 10):

You could simply use the Response object:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
```

And set the Content-Type in it that way:

```
return new Response($image, 200, array('Content-Type' => 'image/png'));
```

Comment: Good answer. Could you just post how that $image look like? I mean: having an image on disk, how do I get its data to store in $image before sending it in the Response? Thanks a lot

Comment: It could be an image generated from gd or read on the disk through file_get_contents for example.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution might be [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/request/mime_type.html) as image is not one of symfony2 supported formats on the Request object.

Also:

```
static protected function initializeFormats()
{
    static::$formats = array(
        'html' => array('text/html', 'application/xhtml+xml'),
        'txt'  => array('text/plain'),
        'js'   => array('application/javascript', 'application/x-javascript', 'text/javascript'),
        'css'  => array('text/css'),
        'json' => array('application/json', 'application/x-json'),
        'xml'  => array('text/xml', 'application/xml', 'application/x-xml'),
        'rdf'  => array('application/rdf+xml'),
        'atom' => array('application/atom+xml'),
        'rss'  => array('application/rss+xml'),
    );
}
```

are Symfony's Request object default available formats. Can check in [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.php).

Good luck!